# how to compare two arrays of strings

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following arrays of strings:

```
array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
array2 = ["a", "c", "b"]
array3 = ["a", "b"]
array4 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

How can I compare the arrays so that:

```
array1 is array2 #false
array1 is array3 #false
array1 is array4 #true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the keyword `is` (which compiles to `===`), but you can add a new `is` method to the prototype of `Array`:

```
Array::is = (o) ->
  return true if this is o
  return false if this.length isnt o.length
  for i in [0..this.length]
    return false if this[i] isnt o[i]
  true
```

Then use it like

```
array1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
array2 = ["a", "c", "b"]
array3 = ["a", "b"]
array4 = ["a", "b", "c"]

alert array1.is array2
alert array1.is array3
alert array1.is array4
```